# Unusual series expansion - how to find coefficients?

Tags: polynomials, formal-power-series

I have encountered an equality
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty p_{3n}(t)\left(\frac t{(1-t)(1-2t)}\right)^n=\frac{1-2t}{1-4t}.
$$
I know that $p_0(t)=1$, $p_3(t)=2(1-t)^2$, while for $n>1$, $p_{3n}(t)$ is a polynomial in $t$ of degree $3n$ with integer coefficients, with leading term $-4^{n-1}t^{3n}$ and divisible by $2(1-t)^2$.

How much can be said about these polynomials given the equality? Specifically, I need to determine $p_{3n}(0)$. Most likely, the above equality does not suffice to do this, what kind of additional information could you think of which would help to find the constant terms?

I've never seen problems like this before, I don't even know what are appropriate tags.

Comment: What if you expanded the series in terms of powers of $1/(1-t)$ and $1/(1-2t)$, added the two series, and divided by 2.  This would give you the correct denominators, then take whatever the numerator is and divide it by $t^n$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Sorry I seem to be too stupid for that. Could you elaborate please?